Reading emails from Gmail using IMAP in C# is slow
I’m having trouble with retrieving emails using IMAP in C#. Here’s what I’m trying to do: - Connect to Gmail using IMAP. - Fetch recent emails efficiently. I’m currently using the MailKit library and the following code:
...

 using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
            client.Authenticate("your-email@gmail.com", "your-password");

            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            // Use a search to only fetch recent emails
            var query = SearchQuery.Recent;
            var uids = inbox.Search(query);

            foreach (var uid in uids)
            {
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
             
            }

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }


...

However, it’s taking a long time to fetch emails, and I’m not sure if I’m doing something wrong.
I’ve already tried limiting the number of messages retrieved.
My internet connection seems fine.
Any advice on optimizing this would be greatly appreciated!

What might be a cause is that you are fetching the ID's of your emails at once, but then fetching the actual email message one by one. I think there should be a method called GetMessages() where you can supply it with your list of ID's. You could also add a Console.WriteLines with 'LineNr' + DateTime.now() to see what takes the longest.
